# Showing the current date using JSTL formatDate tag

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

I am trying to show the current date in my JSP page using JSTL. below is the code I am using.

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" scope="request" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

But the above code is not producing any results? Am I missing anything here or is there any better approach for this? I am using JSTL 1.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to print it without formatting, ${now}, you probably have *null* in there. Do you have this attribute in request scope? Just double check, if yes it might be *null*. If not, then try remove this *scope* attribute from the tag, yeah it doesn't matter but just to make the things clear.

Comment: I don't remember if scope was required for useBean, but if it is, changing it to "page" may alleviate this issue.

Answer (score 5):

`scope=page` works for me